# Can we compare Lucene and Solr index files

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore

We are upgrading Sitecore 8 to 9.3 for that we upgraded Lucene to solr

Can we compare Lucene and Solr index files so that we will be able to know the newly generated solr index files have the same data or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem technically possible as you could use [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke) to explore the content of the Lucene index folder.

While Solr data can be queried via either Sitecore UI, or [Solr admin](https://localhost:8983/solr/#).

Answer (score 0):

No. The indexes are very different even though the underlying technology is similar. What I find best is to have an old and new version of the same site with the same data. Then you can compare site search pages and any part of the site that runs on search.